# how create AlertDialog.Builder in onPostExecuteMethod

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I need to use AlertDialog.Builder  in a onPostExecuteMethos in a class that extends AsyncTask I have only the context of the ultimate Activity.

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param){
....
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle(R.string.erroreTestoConnessione)
                        .setMessage(R.string.erroreConnession)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }
}
```

This class that extends AsyncTask isn't an inner class but another class.
I know that I use

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this)
```

but I obtain a red line with write "is not an enclosing class".

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Where is your `AsyncTask` code?

Comment: In which line getting `is not an enclosing class` message?

Comment: Also what is that context? That context is not being checked for null/invalid. Creating an Alert Dialog in a postExecute is a timebomb and will crash on you (with Invalid Context, Invalid State or Null Pointer Exception). E.g.: the user homes out of your app while your async task is running. Your activity/Context is stopped destroyed by Android because… it's Android. Your timebomb explodes when the AsyncTask ends.

Comment: If you also store the context in an AsyncTask, you're keeping a hard reference to your context (possibly an Activity?), and are therefore leaking the Activity.

Comment: in this--->new AlertDialog.Builder(Activityname.this)

Comment: and so how I can show an AlertDialog in a onPostExecuteMethod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't show `AlertDialog` in `onPostExecute()`. Return some `flag` from your `onPostExecute()` to your activity and

```
if(flag) {
   //Create AlertDialog here
}
```